# Что такое SPI (Интерфейс поставщика услуг)?

Tags: java, интерфейс

Разбирал документацию `Spring`, нашёл там термин **SPI**. Что он означает и какое у него отличие от **API**? Очень желательно с примерами на Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну кратко эту штуку описать с примерами невозможно. На Хабре есть хорошая и вполне понятная [статья на эту тему](https://habr.com/ru/post/118488/).

Если в двух словах попытаться объяснить принцип, то с помощью SPI можно писать расширяемые программы. Если очень-очень грубо и упрощённо, то вы можете запилить интерфейс в одном джарнике (возможно с дефолтной реализацией, но можно и без). А реализацию в другом джарнике.

Вы так к базе подключаетесь. У вас в Java SE есть интерфейс java.sql.Driver, который лежит в своём джарнике. Вы в classpath добавляете реальный драйвер, отдельный джарник, который вы скачали из интернета. И, о чудо, благодаря SPI, джава сама находит в этом совершенно левом джарнике имплементацию для java.sql.Driver.

А всё почему. А всё потому, что, например, в джарнике sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar (это драйвер из инета) есть каталог META-INF.services, а в нём файл java.sql.Driver (название файла, как не трудно догадаться совпадает с именем интерфейса, который тут кто-то собрался реализовывать). А в этом файле есть строка org.sqlite.JDBC. И действительно, если открыть в этом джарнике файл /org/sqlite/JDBC.java, то мы увидим такое:

```
public class JDBC implements Driver {
...
```

Таким образом, благодаря SPI возможна ситуация, что где-то в недрах java.sql лежит интерфейс Driver. Совершенно другие люди, живущие совсем в других местах, написали свой джарник с реализацией этого интерфейса. А мы смогли эту реализацию подложить под этот интерфес, просто поместив джарник с драйвером в classpath.

Не чудо ли?!